# Floating window over apps in jetpack compose foreground service

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My project :
MyActivity.kt (Main activity) -> main activity that has two buttons to start and stop the service.
App.kt (Notfication Channel application) -> class extends Application() that create notification channel.
Foreground.kt (foreground Service) -> extends Service()

```
class Foreground : Service() {
   private lateinit var windowManager:WindowManager
   private lateinit var  floatingView : ComposeView
   
   
   @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
      when (intent?.action){
         "Start" -> startForeground(1,notification())
          "Stop" -> stopSelf()
      }
      return START_NOT_STICKY
   }
   
   
   @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
   override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
      floatingView = ComposeView(this)
      floatingView.setContent {
      myCanvas()
      }
      
      val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
         PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
      )
      
      windowManager.addView(floatingView, params)
   }
   
   override fun onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy()
      windowManager.removeView(floatingView)
   }
   
   
   private fun notification(): Notification {
      return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notification")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
         .setContentTitle("Title")
         .setContentText("Text")
         .build()
   }
   
   override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? = null
}
   @Composable
   fun myCanvas() {
      Canvas(
         modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Transparent)
      ) {
         drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            topLeft = center,
            size = Size(200.dp.toPx(), 200.dp.toPx())
         )
      }
   }
```

Am trying to make : when i start the service, a transparent over app window that display **myCanvas()** content will show.

## My problem :

When i launch the app, then  i press Start Service : the app close and display nothing, and i get this error in android studio logcat :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ0EI.png)

am using default dependencies after i create new blank project
i declared the service in Manifest file, the service work normall and display notification.
am using Canary build of Android studio (HedgeHog 2023.1.1)

i tried to put MyCanvas() in MainActivity and in service i call MyActivity().MyCanvas().
also i put it in new class that extends AppCompatActivity and ComponentActivity, same problem.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.techyourchance.com/jetpack-compose-inside-android-service/

Answer (score 0):

After trying a little, I came up with this solution

MyLifecycleOwner.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner

internal class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner {
    private var mLifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
    private var mSavedStateRegistryController: SavedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
        get() = mLifecycleRegistry

    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
        get() = mSavedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry

    val isInitialized: Boolean
        get() = true

    fun setCurrentState(state: Lifecycle.State) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.currentState = state
    }

    fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)
    }

    fun performRestore(savedState: Bundle?) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(savedState)
    }

    fun performSave(outBundle: Bundle) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performSave(outBundle)
    }

}
```

SimpleService.kt

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonColors
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner
import androidx.savedstate.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner


class SimpleService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    private val windowManager get() = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    private lateinit var  floatingView : ComposeView

    private lateinit var lifecycleOwner: MyLifecycleOwner

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        showOverlay()
    }

    private var windowType = 0
    private var windowFlag = 0
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun showOverlay() {
         windowType = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) {
             @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR
         } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        }
        windowFlag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            windowType,
            windowFlag,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        floatingView = ComposeView(this)
        floatingView.setContent {
            ComposeView(
                clickScope = {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bye bye ComposeView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    stopSelf()
                },
                text = "ComposeView"
            )
        }

        lifecycleOwner = MyLifecycleOwner()
        lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)

        floatingView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
        floatingView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)
        
        windowManager.addView(floatingView, params)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        if (floatingView.parent != null) {
            floatingView.clearAnimation()
            floatingView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(null)
            floatingView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(null)
            windowManager.removeView(floatingView)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeView(
    clickScope: () -> Unit = {},
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
    text: String,
    border: BorderStroke = BorderStroke(1.5.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
) {
    Button(
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(8.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        border = border,
        colors = colors,
        onClick = { clickScope() },
        content = {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = 10.dp,
                        top = 5.dp,
                        end = 10.dp,
                        bottom = 5.dp,
                    ),
                text = text,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                    fontSize = 23.sp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```